# What is the term used to describe when two different things both rely on each other?

Tags: terminology

For example, to increase membership we need to increase activities, but to increase activities we need more members.

Comment: In addition to the answer below, *interdependent*, you might also consider "mutually reinforcing" if you think an increase in one will tend to lead to an increase in the other.

Comment: parallelism or antithesis ?

Comment: They need to work in *synergy*.

Answer (score 4):

**Interdependent**

> Mutually dependent: *"Our physiology and that of the plants we eat are not only biochemically similar but interdependent"* (Cindy Engel). - [American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/interdependent)

Should you want a negative version, there is the IT term *deadly embrace*, where two pieces of computer code each wait for the other in an endless loop. It's not pretty.

Answer (score 2):

This predicament is sometimes called a  [Catch-22.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catch-22) This phrase was used in the novel by Joseph Heller and was based on the difficulty of dealing with  bureaucracy.

A common example is the  [Permissions Paradox.](http://www.fivepatterns.com/pattern3.php) This is the predicament of being unable to get a job because you do not have experience, and being unable to get experience because you do not have a job.

A more informal reference is the Hole in my Bucket syndrome, based on the humorous [song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_a_Hole_in_My_Bucket) in which it is impossible to repair a bucket without water, and impossible to fetch water without a bucket.